# O que é 'binding time' no contexto de desenvolvimento?

Tags: terminologia

No estudo de qualidade de software me deparei com esse termo 'binding time' (Tempo de ligação) e fiquei um tanto quanto perdido no conceito. Então, o que exatamente é?

Comment: https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Programming_Languages/Binding pode ser uma boa leitura

Answer (score 1):

Para entender o que é *Binding time*, podemos começar pelo o que significa *Binding*.

O termo *Binding* neste contexto é o ato de fazer uma [associação](http://cs.loc.edu/~chu/COSI350/Ch4/bound.html), seja de um atributo, símbolo, entidade ou uma operação.

O termo *Binding Time* é **quando** isto irá ocorrer. Os momentos que existem para isto são [vários](http://www.toves.org/books/bind/):

- em **tempo de programação**: quando o programador escrever o código
- em **tempo de compilação**: quando o compilador cria o arquivo de execução (`.class` no Java, `.dll` no C#, etc).
- em **tempo de carregamento**: quando o sistema operacional inicia o programa. Uma variável estática pode ficar limitada a um espaço na memória.
- em **tempo de execução**: quando o programa está rodando. O *bind* ocorre com uma variável local não estática em um espaço na memória.

Algumas das explicações acima podem ser válidas apenas para [algumas linguagens](http://cs.loc.edu/~chu/COSI350/Ch4/bound.html). Outros autores preferem desconsiderar alguns deles ou adicionar outros. Mas o objetivo aqui é passar o conceito.

As maiorias das decisões de *binding time* estão relacionadas as variáveis, que possuem diversas propriedades: nome, escopo, tipo, local na memória e valor. Todas elas podem ser determinadas em tempo de compilação ou execução.

Abaixo vou apresentar um **exemplo** bem simples mostrando a diferença de *binding time* em tempo de programação e tempo de execução.

Considere que deseja *printar* um valor na tela. No Java, podemos fazer:

```
String valor = "Alô Mundo";
System.out.println(valor);
```

No exemplo acima, o valor é sempre `Alô Mundo` e foi decidido pelo programador. Ou seja, é um *binding time* em **tempo de programação**.

Porém, se o código for alterado para receber este valor do usuário:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String valor = scanner.nextLine();
System.out.println(valor);
```

O *binding time* passa a ser por **tempo de execução**, pois só sera possível saber o valor da variável durante a execução do programa.